# Error:Failed to resolve: Android-Iconics:library-core:unspecified

Tags: android, android-studio

### Error:Failed to resolve: Android-Iconics:library-core:unspecified

So, i got this error as

> Error:Failed to resolve: Android-Iconics:library-core:unspecified

in my Android Studio 2.1 Preview 3 after i tried to compile

> compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.5.0.1'

I have tried many other options but failed to compile it in any way. I have also added iconic library but still it gives me same error.
So, can anyone help me out with this ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.10@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.5.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have faced some problem, but the solution is add "@aar" after version name of library. like below...

```
compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.6.0.1@aar'
```

**Full dependencies code**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.11@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.6.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'
}
```

This was worked for me and Gradle sync successfully with out error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Although i did solve this problem many days ago but i do still want to answer it.**

Answer by Jaldeep Asodariya is correct.

```
 compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Now here we have two option:

1. Either add `@aar` at the end library and do not add `transitive = false`, just don't add anything, it will work. If you do not add anything then Transitive is true by default.
2. If you really are into transitive then you should always mention it as `true`. If it is false then it will show this error.It's like whenever we fetch library `@aar` then transitive should be true in most of cases.

Besides other than that, you can always check the github's error wikis of library.